# Jquery miss post 18 char value

Tags: jquery, numbers

I am trying to code a simple admin interface with simple jq operations for validating posts. In my database the post ids are stored like, "204906887878148096" ( 18 chars ), when i echo it is normal but when i send it to alertbox or to script it is like "204906887878148100" what can cause this?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function setOnay(id,durum)
{
alert(id);
page = "admin_ajax.php?id="+id+"&durum="+durum;
alert(page);
$.post(page, function(data){
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
if (data.trim() == "1") {
     document.getElementById("durum"+id).innerHTML="<b>ONAYLANDI</b>";
} else if (data.trim() == "2") {
     document.getElementById("durum"+id).innerHTML="<b>SİLİNDİ</b>";
//} else if (data.trim() == "3") {
 //      document.getElementById("durum"+id).innerHTML="<b>Silindi</b>";
    } else {
    alert("Onay mekanizmasında hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz!");
}   
 },text);

}
</script>
```

the html part;

```
<td width="" align="center"><span id="<?php echo 'durum'.$tweet_id; ?>">
<a href="#"      onclick="setOnay(<? echo $tweet_id; ?>,1)"><img src="admin/check.png"/>
</a>  <a href="#" onclick="setOnay(<? echo $tweet_id; ?>,2)"><img src="admin/delete.png"/></a></span></td>
```

Comment: seems like you should check the limits on the integer datatype in jquery and your server.. you could be exceeding them. What language do you use in the back-end?

Comment: You don't need a number anywhere near that large a number - what are you doing smashing Hadrons?

Answer (score 1):

The largest integer allowed in javascript is +/- 9007199254740992

[ECMA Section 8.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

You could pass it through as a string instead, this would solve your problem.

Comment: these are the standart twitter, tweet_ids. i am trying to code a project on that. it is written in pure php and running on windows server. @ahren can you give an example?

Comment: sure @OnurÇakı , in your example, all you'd need to do is echo quotes in your links.
`onclick="setOnay('<? echo $tweet_id; ?>',1)`
In my example above, I've used single-quotes, as the link markup is using double-quotes. Hope this helps!